# Engine misfires when cold

Tags: engine, misfire, citroen

I have a Citroen C3, 2004, and noticed that lately, when cold, the engine on occasion misfires when driving, until it seems to warm up. It is around 5c today.

I have connected an ODB2 unit and it has given me the following fault codes;
p0200 - which seems to be injector malfunction
p1336 - which seems to be high misfire on several cylinders (unspecified).

I am concerned, as the car has recently (3 months ago) gone through an expensive service and MOT.

Is this something can will pass, or should it be fixed. And if so, would the fix likely be pricy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Water ingress into the ECU is a common issue on these (the build quality on that era C3 is about on a par with a house of cards made by a blind arthritic Labrador to be honest) and it produces the sorts of symptoms you've been seeing. A new unit is ~ £300 from a specialist or it's about £200 to have the existing one rebuilt.

For a relatively common car that's worth about £300-350 on a good day that's a tough sell. If you like the car and know it to be mechanically sound otherwise it might be worth it though - "better the devil you know" can apply here. I would be making plans to change it in the longer term though, in my experience getting 13 years of life out of one these cars is actually a pretty good run and as they get older electrical issues (such as what you've just encountered) can abound, in addition to the one you've already run in to the injector sensors are another weak point.

Answer (score 0):

To make a long story short; after the engine stopped working and the car was towed to the garage, turns out that the ECU had water in it and was in need of replacement.

Looks like it might have to be scrapped, because, according to the garage it would be too expensive to replace and reprogram the unit.

Time to look for a new car :(

Comment: Do not scrap the car for the sake of an ECU. I'm an auto electrician and it does my head in when I see massive quotes for ECU replacement. There is rarely a reason to buy a brand new ECU. You can either get it repaired by an ECU specialist or any good auto electrician can reprogram a used or reconditioned ECU.